# How to print multiple filters of a pivot table at once?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a pivottable with filter. The filter contains a list from 1 to 20, each of which must be printed separately. That is, each time I have to change the filter and print the filtered result.
Is there any solution to print all of them at once?

Thanks,
Dio

Comment: Only by using a Macro.

Comment: Thanks, so it means that I have to post it in Stackoverflow. Am I right?

Comment: No, that means that you have to write a macro, I think ;)

Comment: Ya, I got it. I meant the forum http://stackoverflow.com/.  Thanks anyway. :)